# Angular and Breeze fetchMetaData

Tags: angularjs, breeze, promise, q

I'm curious if there are any alternatives to fetching meta data from breeze when using Angular.  Since $q and Q promises don't play nice with each other I decided to only use Q.js promises and not $q.   In my controller I'm checking if the metaDataStore is empty:

```
  if (mainDataService.manager.metadataStore.isEmpty())
            {
                $log.info('metadataStore is empty') ;

                mainDataService.getMetaData()
                  .then(function ()
                  {
                     EnableCreateButton();
                  });
            }
```

The basic idea if I don't have meta data is to go fetch it and then enable the buttons that will allow me to create a new record.

To accomplish this I define a Q Promise in my data service then after breeze resolves the promise I resolve my promise.

```
  function getMetaData()
{

    var myMetaDataPromise = Q.defer();

    Q.delay(0).then(function () {

        manager.metadataStore.fetchMetadata(serviceName).then(function () {
            myMetaDataPromise.resolve();
        });

    });
    return myMetaDataPromise.promise;



}
```

Any suggestions to make this cleaner would be great.  One thought I had was to define the promise in the controller and have the data service just return the breeze promise.  I just thought that would clutter the controller up and not separate out the concerns.

Comment: In the light of "Differences between Kris Kowal's Q and $q" [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$q), you might like to reconsider your decision to use only Q.js promises and not $q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the new [`to$q` extension in breeze labs on github](https://github.com/IdeaBlade/Breeze/blob/master/Breeze.Client/Scripts/Labs/breeze.to%24q.js) which have been using pretty extensively to good effect.

We haven't documented it yet but the comments explain how to "install" it and use it.

Your `mainDataService.getMetaData()` could then be:

```
return manager.metadataStore.fetchMetadata(serviceName).to$q();
```

and subsequently you do as you intended:

```
mainDataService.getMetaData()
    .then(function() { EnableCreateButton(); });
```

You are now in the land of `$q`. Angular will `$apply` your EnableCreateButton automatically.